# Interface between ROS and UR Polyscope

Tags: ros, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to interface between UR's Polyscope and ROS.
For example, can you command a wait function in Polyscope and let ROS take over control of the robot in the meanwhile?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327252/interface-between-ros-and-ur-polyscope/) by [stijn_de_lo](https://answers.ros.org/users/43467/stijn_de_lo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going to answer this in the context of `ur_modern_driver` and `universal_robot`, as those are the packages typically used -- right now -- with UR robots.

---

This is not something that is supported by `ur_modern_driver`.

It does only upload a small urscript program when trajectories are actually being executed ([this one](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/blob/c6637030695fff154d387882761dc3024977a55e/src/ros/trajectory_follower.cpp#L30-L84)), and that program does quit when the trajectory is finished (or at least: if you're not using `ros_control`), but uploading any program to the controller will automatically shut down whatever was already running.

You could potentially achieve what you are asking by integrating the urscript program `ur_modern_driver` uploads when executing trajectories into a larger urscript program but only allow actual robot control when you'd like to, but that is not something that `ur_modern_driver` supports out-of-the-box (so would require custom development).

---

The work currently being done by FZI & UR on a new driver does support the scenario you describe, but that driver hasn't been released yet.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0